# I cannot determine why I am getting the Syntax Error "unterminated string literal" in Python called from Excel VBA via xlwings

Tags: python, excel, vba, string-literals, xlwings

I am very inexperienced Python user and only beginning to learn the language. After checking multiple possibilities I still cannot determine why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

The python code is:

```
import numpy as np
import xlwings as xw

def formatInfluencer():
    #
    # FormatInfluencer Macro
    #
    #
    Selection.NumberFormat = '0'
    with_variable0 = Selection
    with_variable0.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    with_variable0.VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    with_variable0.WrapText = False
    with_variable0.Orientation = 0
    with_variable0.AddIndent = False
    with_variable0.IndentLevel = 0
    with_variable0.ShrinkToFit = False
    with_variable0.ReadingOrder = xlContext
    with_variable0.MergeCells = False
    with_variable1 = Selection.Interior
    with_variable1.Pattern = xlSolid
    with_variable1.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    with_variable1.Color = 10092543
    with_variable1.TintAndShade = 0
    with_variable1.PatternTintAndShade = 0
```

The vba code is:

```
Sub formatInfluencerNew()
    
    RunPython "import MetaFormats; MetaFormats.formatInfluencer()"
    

End Sub
```

The full error message is:

---

### Error

File "", line 1

```
import xlwings.utils;xlwings.utils.prepare_sys_path("False;Book2;C:\\Users\\tobin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Excel\\XLSTART\\xlwings.xlam;;;;C:\\Users\\tobin\\Documents\\Python\"); import MetaFormats; MetaFormats.formatInfluencer()

                                                    ^
```

SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 1)

### Press Ctrl+C to copy this message to the clipboard.

### OK

I'm expecting the code to apply a particular format to the selected cell(s).

Comment: The string in the line shown in the error isn't terminated.  There is a double-quote at the end, but it's escaped, so it's part of the string rather than a string terminator.  Change `\"` to `"` to terminate the string.

Comment: Thank, @TomKarzes.  I had added a backslash to the default path for .py files.  Eliminating that backslash worked.  Cheers